# How to use CSS position(relative, absolute) with percentage (height, width) dimension?

Tags: css

So many question & answers are there related to this topic but no where i found the like following mentioned case. All describes **If you want to  set the height and width in percentage, set the parent height in percentage first** but still I did not get clarity.

For example: Following ID and class of block of drupal 7, and my code which starts from the "box1" which I added using body(Editor) of that block.

```
<div id="block-block-1">
    <div class="block-inner">
        <div class="block-content">
            <div class="box1">
                <a class="box2">
                    <span class="box3">For Title</span>
                    <span class="box4">For Text</span>
                    <span class="box5">For Image</span>
                </a>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**So, for which part of code is parent for which one.

1. **Height & width Aspect:** Do I have to make the #block-block-1 {height: 100%, width: 100%}, and it will be apply to every one. Or do I have to add at each stage, but if I do that, then automatically all `div`, `a` sections will be 100%, that not make any sense.
2. **Position Aspect:** Now The other aspect of positioning of `Div` with combination of `Position:relative` and `Position:absolute`, where, it states that parent `div` should be relative and inside that all div should be absolute and set its position using `top`, `right` and `left`. But same question one's Relative position is other's absolute position, so again it creates contradictory same as height and width.

So, what is the right way to use this height/weight(in percent) and position aspect simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few examples to get you some insight in position and more, hope it helps to bring your css-skills to a next level.

**Important read html code first and look what happen in result**

First of all, understand block-level/inline elements.

```css
* {
  outline: 1px solid
}
div.iHaveKids {
  padding: 25px
}
/* all childs of div*/

div > * {
  background-color: red
}
b {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}
b.running {
  margin-left: 40px
}
span {
  background-color: pink
}
div.clearMe {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>This is a beatifull block-level element</div>
<span>This is inline element</span>
<div>a block-level element width is, if not set, 100%</div>
<div class="iHaveKids">a block-level element height is, if not set, designed to fit hes childeren
  <div>I'm a child</div>
  <div>Me tooooooo</div>
  <div><b>A block element can have margins and/or paddings but i'm a inline element</b>
  </div>
  <div><b>Even when i have a width set i just ignore them, because i'm a inline element</b>
  </div>
  <div><b class="running away">however i can set margin-left and/or margin-right</b>
  </div>
</div>
<span>i'm an inline element<span>me toooo and i'm inside an inline element</span>
<div class="clearMe">block-level element</div>
<div>block-level elements start at a new-line in the document even if there is enough room</div>
</span>
```

Now position:

```css
* {
  outline: 1px solid;
}
div.example {
  background: red;
}
.example.ex1,
.example.ex2,
.example.ex3,
.example.ex4,
.example.ex5,
.example.ex10 {
  position: absolute;
}
span {
  background-color: yellow
}
div.ex4 {
  z-index: 2500;
}
.example.ex6,
.example.ex7,
.example.ex8,
.example.ex9 {
  position: relative;
}
.ex8,
.ex9 {
  top: 40px;
}
.ex9 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
.ex10 {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>im a block-level element, i have by default position:static</div>
<div class="example ex1">im a absolute element, i have position:absolute
  <span>my parent has an absolute position i'm just an inline element</span>
</div>
<div class="example ex2">im a absolute element, i have position:absolute
  <span>hm hm hm hm hm  my parent has also position:absolute, if no top,left,bottom,right is defined than i will place my self in the normal document flow without looking to position:absolute elements, floated elementes, position:fixed elements, position, relative elements</span>
  <span>if two or more position:absolute elements are in the same place without a stacking-order than is the one that was latest in document-flow who get higher stakcing-order</span>
</div>

<div>
  <div>make</div>
  <div>some</div>
  <div>room</div>
  <div>for example 3</div>
  <div>for example 4</div>
  <div>for example 5</div>
</div>


<div class="example ex3">Example 3</div>
<div class="example ex4">Example 4:: ex3, ex5 has no stacking order but ex4 does, autor-define stacking are higher than browser setted stackings</div>
<div class="example ex5">Example 5</div>

<div>
  <div>make</div>
  <div>some</div>
  <div>room</div>
  <div>for example 6</div>
  <div>for example 7</div>
  <div>for example 8</div>
</div>

<div class="example ex6">Example 6, i have position: relative</div>
<div class="example ex7">Example 7, i have position: relative<span>hm hm hm hm hm  my parent has also position:relative, if no top,left,bottom,right is defined than i will place my self in the normal document flow</span>top
</div>
<div class="example ex8">Example 8, i have position: relative and bottom: 40px;<span>meaning i will move myself 40px away from the top where the document-flow woulkd place me</span>
</div>

<div class="example ex9">I have position:relative i'm also a block-element and have a width of 500px and an height of 500px; i also have top: 40px;

  <div class="example ex10">i'm a block-level element with position:absolute inside of an element with position:relative i also have bottom: 0 so i place myself 0px away from the bottom line of my <b>nearest positioned ancestor</b> if i have no nearest positioned ancestor i take
    the document root</div>

</div>
```

Than finally % width and height

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
div > div {
  position: absolute;
}
div.parent {
  top: 10px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}
div.child {
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  i'm position:realtive;

  <div class="child">
    i'm position:absolute;
    <br>i first look top, right, bottom, left
    <br>than i look to my content and fit even if i'm a block-level element
    <br>to calculate percentage i look to my the parent
    <br>my parent is height: 400px
    <br>i use top: 10%;
    <br>what means i will set 40px
    <br>
  </div>

</div>
```

To finally answer your question:

> So, what is the right way to use this height/weight(in percent) and position aspect simultaneously?

**Percentages** are based on **maximum available space**, in last example `top: 400px;` so *10% == 40px* once you understand how things behave ( root, parent, child, siblings, ancestor,.. ) you find this kind of work too so easy for you. Read, read and read even more to learn about difference between any ground of elements.

> Do I have to make the #block-block-1 {height: 100%, width: 100%}, and it will be apply to every one.

Like in examples said, **apply** 'width: 100%`; to an **block-level** element has **no use**. If you ask how **child element behave** on **dimension settings** (width, height, top, right, bottom, left, margin, padding,..) you need to know what kind of element it is (block, inline, grid, flex, table, list, replaced,... element) and know how it behaves.

> But same question one's Relative position is other's absolute position, so again it creates contradictory same as height and width.

An element with `position: absolute;` looks for the **nearest positioned ancestor** element, if **not set** i will look to **document.root**

useful resources:
[Percentage on Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/percentage)
[Lenght properties on css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/)
[The Difference Between “Block” and “Inline” on impressivewebs](http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/)

Comment: Thx, I read several literature on dimensions/font-sizes. I am developing a responsive site using drupal. Could you suggest which dimension unit(px, em, %, vw/vh) to use for which purpose(layout, font-size etc), I mean what is the current best practice?..Thx

Comment: Raw: i use percentages for html, body and element greatest ancestor (within body) '<body><div id="wrapper">example width:90%;</div></body'  >

Comment: Raw i use percentages for font-size because your text remains fully scale able  for mobile devices and for accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example so you can understand how it works.

The parent block `.box2` 100px from the left edge because of the margin.

If you want to position elements with `absolute`, but with the `.box2` as a reference (relatively to it), you have to add `position: relative` on the parent element.

- `.box3` is 0px from the left edge of `.box2`
- `.box4` is 100px from the left edge of `.box2`
- `.box5` is 100px from the right edge of `.box2`

You can also use `top` and `bottom` properties, of course.

```css
.box2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  height: 2em;
  margin-left: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

.box2 span {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
}

.box3 {
  left: 0;
}

.box4 {
  left: 100px;
}

.box5 {
  right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a class="box2">
  <span class="box3">For Title</span>
  <span class="box4">For Text</span>
  <span class="box5">For Image</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Well, that is ok for two set of element, one is parent and one is just its immediate. But question remains same what if we have three or four `div` inside. So if i consider `.box1` so `.box2` is absolute for `.box1` and relative for `.box3`. And moreover I want to use all dimensions in percentage, so which one is parent for which.

Comment: `%` dimensions are based on the direct parent's dimensions. And if you need for example `.box3` to be relative to `.box2`, you **cannot** also have `.box2` relative to `.box1` at the same time.